# Exchange gain or loss on partial payments in Odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-11

I found out Odoo is not creating exchange gains or losses for partial
payments. Only at the time of full payment Odoo is calculating the
exchange difference. This is creating  serious headache for the user,
when they see aged payable, receivable, partner ledger, general
ledger, etc exchange rate is not considered. This is giving the users
wrong information about the payments they have made.

Impacted versions: 11

Steps to reproduce:

1) Make 2 different Multi currency Invoices for the single supplier
2) Modify the current exchange rate under currencies
3) Make a partial payment for one single invoice with exchange difference

Current behavior:
It does not generate the Exchange gain or Loss for the partial invoice payments

Expected behavior:
Irrespective of the full payments or partial, it should generate the Exchange gain or Loss as per the payment date and Invoice record Date

Answer (score 0):

By default Odoo will generate exchange gain or loss only when all invoice paid, on partial payments exchange isn't computing.